# SpeechContexts in Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: google-cloud-speech

When I add words to the SpeechContext, they are not being recognized at all. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
SpeechContext spk = new SpeechContext();
                                spk.Phrases.Add("lingual");


                                var request = new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                                {
                                    StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
                                    {
                                        Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                                        {
                                            Encoding =
                                            RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                                            SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                                            LanguageCode = "sv-SE",

                                        },
                                        InterimResults = true,
                                    }
                                };

                                //request.StreamingConfig.Config.SpeechContexts.
                                request.StreamingConfig.Config.SpeechContexts.Add(spk);

                                streamingCall.WriteAsync(request);
```

Comment: How can you tell it doesn't work?, what is your error message?, what feedback do you have from it?

Comment: please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way instead:

```
var spk = new SpeechContext { Phrases = { "lingual" } };
var request = new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
{
    StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
    {
        Config = new RecognitionConfig()
        {
            Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
            SampleRateHertz = 16000,
            LanguageCode = "sv-SE",
            SpeechContexts = { spk }
        },
        InterimResults = true,
    }
};
```

Hope it helps.